# has n of Strings in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, rubygems, datamapper

I'm writing a client for a web service, and part of their model is a list of strings belonging to a user containing previous usernames the user went by. I'm trying to use DataMapper for my client gem, and my first thought was to use DataMapper's has n syntax, but I can't seem to apply this to Strings. Is there a better way of doing this perhaps?

My current code:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # Some Properties here

  has n, :also_known_as, 'String'
end
```

The error this generates is this:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'cloudsdale'
NoMethodError: undefined method `relationships' for String:Class
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/associations/one_to_many.rb:109:in `finalize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/model.rb:782:in `block in finalize_relationships'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:210:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:210:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/model.rb:782:in `finalize_relationships'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/model.rb:137:in `finalize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core.rb:281:in `block in finalize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/descendant_set.rb:64:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:210:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/ordered_set.rb:319:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/subject_set.rb:210:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/support/descendant_set.rb:63:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core.rb:281:in `finalize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cloudsdale-0.0.1/lib/cloudsdale.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):002:0>
```

The file that the error spawns from is this:

```
# Load in DataMapper
# Change the setup to meet your DB needs
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'abstract::')

# API objects
require 'cloudsdale/version'
require 'cloudsdale/api/api'
require 'cloudsdale/client'

# Models
require 'cloudsdale/models/user'
require 'cloudsdale/models/cloud'
require 'cloudsdale/models/avatar'
require 'cloudsdale/models/ban'
require 'cloudsdale/models/chat'

# Finalize DataMapper so the models Load
DataMapper.finalize
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you use `'String'` here?

```
has n, :also_known_as, 'String'
```

it make no sense, remove it:

```
has n, :also_known_as
```

if you want to set model, use `:model` option:

```
has n, :also_known_as, :model => ModelName
```

and i'm not sure you want to use `String` as model name.

most likely you need an extra model to keep user's previous names:

```
class UserAlias
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # ...
end


class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # ...

  has n, :also_known_as, :model => UserAlias
end
```

Comment: My goal was to simply use the platform string model for the list. From my point of view, it seems a tad bit overkill to use a completely separate model when all I'm storing is a list of strings, thus why I was trying to have DataMapper map the list to the String class.

Comment: You can have database relations only with `DataMapper::Resource` classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to search for older usernames via the datamapper 1.x query DSL you need to define an additional model.

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # ...

  has n, :also_known_as, :model => UserNameHistory
end

class UsernameHistory
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If you do not need to query via the old usernames you can use a serialized large object. As a suggestion you could use the `DataMapper::Property::YAML` from `dm-types` like this:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # ...

  property :also_known_as, YAML
end
```